# PHP exec throw exception not working

Tags: php, exception, exec

I have a script "test.php" which runs in the PHP CLI using command **exec**. 
Inside this file I am using **Exception** for some special cases in order to catch them outside of CLI and stop execution. Unfortunately, the Exception is not thrown, and I do not know why. I cannot use the **exit()** command, so I need to know what is the problem with the following script

```
index.php

$cliObj = new CliClass('test.php');
$cliObj->run();
$cliObj->setOutputFile('../test.txt');

test.php
if ($x == 0) throw new \Exception("TEST");
```

I know that the variable $x is 0, but i Exception is not thrown.

10x!

Comment: Hi @Yair.R.  I write wrong example because i am using \Exception

Comment: Where is the source of `CliClass`? How does it output to test.txt? Are you capturing both `STDERR` and `STDIO`?

Comment: CliClass is on the same level as index.php and it is working because exec execution is started. My command look like this nice -n 19 php -f test.php 2>&1 > ../test.text.

Comment: You cannot throw an exception in ones script that you've `exec`'d in another. Also, since you're not catching the exception in test.php, the following applies: `If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception" message...` http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2):

The code should be like this:

```
if ($x == 0) {
  throw new \Exception("TEST");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that $x is 0? try this :

if ($x == 0) {
  throw new \Exception("it is 0");
}
throw new \Exception("it is not 0");

Comment: How do i catch the exception in index.php? It is thrown now, my bad. In file index.php i tried to put code inside try and catch because message i want to be displayed in index.php

Comment: bind with try and catch(Exception $e) and print the $e error message

Comment: Ok. Please mark this answer as solved if you've got the exception part resolved.

Comment: Hi, i cannot catch the exception from test.php which run in cli inside index.php. Can you help me?